# Sorting with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have this Index action method from which i am passing a result , and i want to sort my table through the same Index Action method how can i pass both the value to view.
here is my index Action method

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
{
    var userCount = db.CountUser();

    return View(userCount.ToList());
}
```

and here is my sorting code:

```
ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";

var teams = from t in db.Teams
            select t;
switch (sortOrder)
{
    case "name_desc":
        teams = teams.OrderByDescending(t => t.TeamName);
        break;

    default:
        teams = teams.OrderBy(t => t.TeamName);
        break;
}
```

Comment: before return View(userCount.ToList()); add ViewBag.Teams=teams; and by this you will be able to send both results to the view

Comment: So you want both **userCount.ToList()** and sorted **teams** passed into your Index view?

Comment: @ Hadi Hassan and how can i call this in view, rite now i am calling it in view like this manner
<th style="width:15%">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Team Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })
                                   
                                </th>

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
{
    var userCount = db.CountUser();

    ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : sortOrder;

    var teams = from t in db.Teams
                select t;

    switch ((string)ViewBag.NameSortParm)
    {
        case "name_desc":
            teams = teams.OrderByDescending(t => t.TeamName);
            break;

        default:
            teams = teams.OrderBy(t => t.TeamName);
            break;
    }

    ViewBag.Teams = teams.ToList();

    return View(userCount.ToList());
}
```

And use `ViewBag.Teams` in your view.

However, proper solution for that I think would be creating a proper Model that contains both collections:

```
public class MyIndexViewModel
{
    public List<CountUser> CountUsers { get; set; }
    public List<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
{
    var userCount = db.CountUser();

    ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : sortOrder;

    var teams = from t in db.Teams
                select t;

    switch ((string)ViewBag.NameSortParm)
    {
        case "name_desc":
            teams = teams.OrderByDescending(t => t.TeamName);
            break;

        default:
            teams = teams.OrderBy(t => t.TeamName);
            break;
    }

    return View(new MyIndexViewModel { CountUsers = userCount.ToList(), Teams = teams.ToList() });
}
```

And also you need to change model type in your View to `MyIndexViewModel`

Comment: var userCount = db.CountUser(); here actually i calling a stored procedure CountUser(); and second thing is it possible to pass a switch a dynamic expression

Comment: It is really up to you what is **db.CountUser()** as far as it returning IEnumerable so you can call **ToList** it is fine. And yes you are right, you cannot use it right away but **switch ((string)ViewBag.NameSortParm)** gonna work.

Comment: Thanku okay now after this solution
switch ((string)ViewBag.NameSortParm)
where should i call these to viewbag
 <th style="width:15%">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Team Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })
                                </th>
which view bag should be call in this <th> tag